# Open URL from HTML5 xcode app

Tags: xcode, html, cordova

I initially started doing this app with Dreamweaver and phonegap build.  After running into some issue I bypassed Phonegap build and imported my project directly into xcode (my first time using).

The problem I am having is when someone clicks the url it opens up in the app instead of the browser.  I am very new to apps in general and a baby when it comes to xcode so forgive me if this is pretty cut and dry.

My anchor looks like this:

```
<a data-role="button" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#07a54a;">
```

Like I said when someone clicks that, its like it opens within the app and there is no way to get back to the app unless you kill it.

Specifically my questions is how do I get this url to open outside the app in the phones browser?  I have watched and read numerous tutorials talking about .h and .m files, but all of these seem to be using the drag and drop story board which I dont have or know how to use.

Can someone tell me how I can have this (and other absolute url's) open in the browser outside of the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an "HTML5 Xcode app".  You say you bypassed PhoneGap and imported it directly, but that's not possible.  Xcode doesn't know what to do with plain HTML 5.  It sounds like you are still using PhoneGap, in which case you follow whatever the normal PhoneGap procedure for opening links in Safari is.

Comment: I found my problem and it was indeed poorly worded.. Just waiting for the time to pass to answer my own question ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it: Thanks http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Poorly worded on my end, app uses phonegap :D